# How to remove all files and subdirectories in a directory WITHOUT deleting the directory in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, rm

Is there a command to remove all files and subdirectories in a directory **without** deleting the directory?

For example if I have directory `dontDeleteMe` with subdirectories `1`, `2`, `3` and each subdirectory has a few pictures in it, how can I remove the subdirectories `1`, `2`, and `3` and all the files in the them, without removing the parent directory `dontDeleteMe`?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

To remove everything *in* a directory without removing the directory, type in:

```
rm -rfv dontDeleteMe/*
```

Please note, the `/*` part is very important. If you put a space before the `*`, it will delete all your files in your current directory.

Also, be very careful playing with `rm`, `-r` and `*` all in the same command. They can be a disastrous combination.

**Update:**  Okay, I realized if you do have hidden/dot files [filenames with dots at the beginning, e.x. `.hidden`] then this will leave those files intact.

So really, the simplest solution to the **original question** is:

```
rm -rfv dontDeleteMe && mkdir dontDeleteMe
```

Another one would be to use `find`'s `-exec` option or pipe to `xargs` (below):

```
find dontDeleteMe/* -print0  | xargs -0  rm -rv
```

Comment: Can you give an example of using xargs? What is xargs?

Comment: @justingrif:  `find dontDeleteMe/* -print0  | xargs -0  rm -rv`  I believe in most cases this will work, regardless of spaces, and what not.  But cd to `/tmp/` and make a test directory and try it out. :)

Comment: Oh, and from the manpage:    *"xargs - build and execute command lines from standard input"*

Comment: Re-making a directory does not equal deleting its contents. e.g. umask directory permission differences, owner differences, etc... [enzotib's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/72469/234837) would solve the issues with your original syntax

Comment: This is not a good answer. Using * is dangerous, and won't work on dotfiles without "dotglob" (see below). `rm -rf dontDeleteMe && mkdir dontDeleteMe` doesn't ensure that the dir is re-created with the same permissions/owner(s).
Instead, use one of the `find dontDeleteMe/ -mindepth 1 -delete` variants below.

Comment: @NilsToedtmann, with all due respect, I did give fair warning in my answer that the * should be used with care.

Answer (score 47):

Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) ant type this:

```
find somedir -mindepth 1 -delete
```

This will match all files and directories within `somedir` and its (grand-)children including "hidden" dot files but excluding `somedir` itself because of `-mindepth 1`, then `-delete` them.

Comment: This works well for me, although is it fundamentally safer than using "rm -rf"?

Comment: @EricP The main difference between `find` with `-mindepth 1` and `rm` is that the former will keep the directory and only delete its contents. It's not safer per se, both will delete everything in the directory without confirmation if you have the permissions to do so. But `find` is more flexible (it has many more options than `rm`).

Comment: Also working nicely with patterns: `find */web/sites/default/files -delete`

Answer (score 31):

The only reason `rm -r ./*` do not always work is because you can have hidden files and/or folder that are not matched by `*`.

To this end, `bash` provide an option to make `*` match everything, even hidden objects:

```
cd dont-delete-me
shopt -s dotglob
rm -r ./*
```

It can be useful to reset `dotglob` to its default (unset) state, if you keep on using the shell where you executed the above commands:

```
shopt -u dotglob
```

Comment: It can also not work when you have a large number of files

Answer (score 6):

```
find /dontDeleteMe/ -xdev -depth -mindepth 1 -exec rm -Rf {} \;
```

Use `xdev` option to delete files only within device boundary.

Comment: GNU find has `-delete`. It implies `-depth` and is easier to remember than `-depth -exec rm -Rf {} \;`

Answer (score 4):

To delete (in terminal) all files and subdirectories except for the base directory named "dontdelete":

```
rm -rf dontdelete/*
```

Comment: This doesn't delete hidden files, so "all files" might be too bold a statement.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `find` with the `-delete` flag:

```
find dontDeleteMe/* -delete
```

The `/*` is important as it tells `find` to search only INSIDE the folder called "dontDeleteMe".

Also ensure that the `-delete` flag is at the end of the `find` command.

Comment: This solution doesn't delete any hidden files, unless you enable `dotglob`. Otherwise, using the `-mindepth 1` flag option seems the only way to get it working.

Answer (score 3):

```
rm -rf  directory/{.*,/*}
```

What says:

Remove all files starting with . in "directory" and all other files too.

Though as kindly noted by [Neftas](https://askubuntu.com/users/143230/neftas) this solution **is not safe!**

Safer solution is:

```
 rm -rf directory/!(.|..)
```

Comment: This command could potentially be dangerous, since you're also including `.` and `..` directories. This may be avoided by changing `{.*}` to `{.??*}`, but then you won't delete hidden files with only one character, such as `.a`.

Comment: what's about this?    rm -rf  directory/!(.|..)

Comment: That looks like a much better solution than what I came up with. May I suggest you edit your answer?

Comment: suggestion accepted )

Answer (score 2):

There is an even simpler answer:

1. `cd dontDeleteMe`
2. `rm -rf *`

Basic system administration lecture time: **Be sure to pay attention to where you are when you use sweeping commands like this.**

I can't say that enough.  I've had to recover a box because someone wasn't paying attention and typed in `rm -rf *` while in /.

*nix assumes that if you are root or if you are sudo-ing as root that you know what you are doing.  So make sure that you know what you're doing before you do it.

An alternative which makes sure your 'cd' command works before you issue the 'rm' is to use

```
cd dontDeleteMe && rm -rf *
```

Comment: This is a dangerous suggestion.  What you want is:  `cd dontDeleteMe && rm -rf *`

Comment: @Izkata Or make sure to check that the cd operation was successful, before issuing the rm command.

Comment: @EliahKagan That's exactly what my code snippet does...

Comment: Actually it's not any more or any less dangerous than what you suggest.  All the && does is to chain the two commands together so that they execute at the same time.  If anything my method is actually SAFER since you have to stop and .look before you execute the rm -rf *.  Pausing to double check is always better.

Comment: @user30619 The `&&` operator doesn't just chain the commands together; it requires that each command be successful before the next one will be executed. If the `cd` command fails for any reason (directory doesn't exist, privileges, etc) then the `rm` command won't be executed. I'd call that safer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why this is so complex, help me if i am wrong

```
cd DoNotDeleteDir #<- this is just to make sure we are inside
find . | xargs rm -rf
```

That's it

Comment: This has the slight flaw of trying to delete the current directory as well, which, of course, doesn't work, because it's still in use as the working directory of the invoking shell.

Comment: One *can* delete the current directory from inside it--and then be "in" a nonexistent directory. `rmdir ../tmp`, from an empty directory called `tmp`, will do that. The technique in *this* answer doesn't delete the current directory because the `rm` command special-cases the specific *pathnames* `.` and `..`, refusing to operate on them. Thus `rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '.'` (from GNU rm, which provides `/bin/rm` in Ubuntu) is quite literally what is happening. `rmdir .` behaves similarly, though it shows a less illuminating `Invalid argument` error. @DavidFoerster

Answer (score 0):

1. Easiest thing for me - a windows expert but an ubuntu newbie
2. Click the Files icon on the launcher
3. Navigate to the directory where the
   files and folders are located that you want to delete
4. Right Click in a blank area of the window next to the files and click "Open in Terminal" - leave the Files window open
5. A terminal window will open and will be "set" to the folder you located
6. You can type "dir" (disregard quotes when i say type) and press enter for the terminal to show a list of files and folders  - just to prove you are "in" the right folder
7. type "rm -rf *" and press enter
8. depending on size of folders/files to delete system will pause
9. When terminal prompt returns, the Files window you had opened will now say "Folder is Empty"
10. I had success with this method and it gave me comfort to see the files/folder both in the Files window and as a result of the Dir command in the terminal window
11. I was also comforted that the Files window displayed the folder now empty - especially since I had been chasing these files around looking for the trash folder that they were in
12. Thanks to everyone else who submitted answers - it was very informative

Comment: That seems quite convoluted – especially since you're going to end up running `rm -rf *` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf ${PWD}/*
```

will clear the present working directory

Answer (score 0):

I would use `find` as suggested by [guciek's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/194391/8822), and add `-xdev` to make sure it doesn't descend into other filesystems:

```
find 'dontDeleteMe' -xdev -mindepth 1 -deletea
```

(I added quotes in case the real path contains spaces)

An alternative with Bash and `rm` could be

```
rm -rf 'dontDeleteMe'/{*,.[!.]*}
```

This would also remove hidden files, without producing errors. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62795154/111036) for details.