# Does using -v (verbose) slow commands down?

Tags: command-line, rm

In this question: [How to remove all files and subdirectories in a directory WITHOUT deleting the directory in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72446/how-to-remove-all-files-and-subdirectories-in-a-directory-without-deleting-the-d) it is asked how to delete all file in a folder, and not the folder itself.

[Matt](https://askubuntu.com/users/17448/matt)s exelent answer includes the use of the -v flag to the 'rm' command.

```
rm -rfv dontDeleteMe && mkdir dontDeleteMe
```

The command I left with was the one above. Certainly useful indeed, but does the -v flag in 'rm' and/or in general slow down tasks done through the command line?

I have a folder with .txt-files (about 100.000 of them) that I have created, deleted and recreated for myself a few times now. Some times with rm, some times in the filebrowser, and I get the feeling it's even slower to use the rm-command as show above. Does the -v flag have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes, the -v flag slows down the command.

Most, if not all softwares(or commands) would check if a flag is provided, and then execute a bunch of code related to the flag. In case of the -v flag, they would likely execute a bunch of output commands(like `echo` or `printf`), which they rather would have skipped without the flag.

This means more instruction cycles for the processor and thus more execution time.

It is better if you don't use -v flag if you are not going to read/need the messages.

On the other hand, the CLI would/should be faster than GUI, assuming that you don't include time required to type the commands and pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

From [this blog of superuser](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/01/qotw-does-running-commands-in-verbose-mode-slow-them-down/) this image explains the slowness very well

[image]

For the specific command in question, the results of the time command are

```
//with -v
real    0m8.753s
user    0m0.816s
sys     0m2.036s

//without -v
real    0m1.282s
user    0m0.124s
sys     0m1.092s
```

this was done with the directory containing 100000 empty files

Comment: I wouldn't speak of "echo commands". Most programs aren't bash scripts so they do *not* call echo. The problem is that they are *writing to stdout* (or *stderr*), in other words, they are performing I/O operations, which require time (I/O is costly) and they also require system calls (which means more context switches and hence more cache miss etc.).

Comment: The main problem with writing to stdout is the actual rendering of that content; if you redirect stdout to a file, or `/dev/null`, performance is not nearly so hampered as displaying text on a terminal emulator.

Comment: As you can see from the graph, the difference in time is negligible if you are talking about response time from a human's point of view. Thus, if you are worried about efficiency for a person watching the command, it's not relevant. It's only relevant for huge numbers of files or for many repeated runs where computer time is precious (e.g. a busy web server or an ancient computer).

Comment: The most impact, and probably the only case where it would really matter, is when you run the command on a remote machine via SSH. Verbose logging may easily generate tens of megabytes of traffic which would have to be transmitted from the host to your console. I once experienced a speedup in order of 10x after removing excessive console logging from a script which I ran via SSH.

Answer (score 7):

Why not find out yourself: use time.

```
$ time rm -rfv dontDeleteMe && mkdir dontDeleteMe
real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s

$ time rm -rf dontDeleteMe && mkdir dontDeleteMe
real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. A difference of 1 ms between single runs of each command could be caused by a lot of factors. Also not clear if you omitted the `-v` output or the directory was empty.

Comment: Not to mention the slow down isn't from the extra executed instructions, but from the process of writing it to a file or the terminal. `time' pretty much redirects the output to `/dev/null'.